# Creating a form using vue.js that renders initial values from db in Phoenix

Tags: vue.js, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have to create a form which is based on schema fields from db, using Vue.js.

I am not sure how to do it and I will be grateful for help.

```
%Example.Users.User{
  schema: [
    %{
      "title" => "name",
      "identifier" => "name",
      "type" => "text",
      "settings" => %{
      "options" =>
      %{"default" => "test_name",
      "placeholder" => "name"}, 
      "validate" =>
      %{"min" => 5,
      "required" => []} 
      },
      "weight" => 0
     },
    %{
      "title" => "email",
      "identifier" => "email",
      "type" => "email",
      "settings" => %{"options" => [], "validate" => []},
      "weight" => 1
     },
    %{
      "title" => "description",
      "identifier" => "description",
      "type" => "text",
      "settings" => %{"options" => [], "validate" => []},
      "weight" => 2
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Some more details might be useful, like: is this a one time conversion or is the schema input dynamic and should the conversion be done on-the-fly? Do you want to use a `changeset` to render (and validate) the form or not? And what did you already try?

Comment: @zwippie , they will be imposed in advance. I am not sure which path to follow, so I am not sure about a `changeset`. For now i am trying to understand Vue.js in order to create a form with it and inject schema data into it. However, I am not getting much :(

Comment: Ah, so it's a one time conversion of a schema to a Vue.js component? Doesn't that mean you can just write those components by hand instead of creating some generic form renderer component in Vue.js? It would really help if you add some hints or example code of what you like to get out of this. (Another question: why not use LiveView instead of Vue.js when you're already using Phoenix?)

Comment: I was wrong, it's just an example of how it might look, so it will be dynamic. I have no idea how I could do this :(